# How to add layout to the Table component in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I am developing application using vaadin framework.

I need to add layout(Form) inside a table component. I have created a table with two column,

This is my code

Table table = new Table();

```
table.addContainerProperty("Id", Integer.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);

for( int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
table.addItem(new Object[] {i, "xyz"}, Integer.valueOf(i));
}

table.setSelectable(true);
table.setSizeFull();
```

When I am clicking on record, I need Form layout which containing TextField's in between the clicked row and next row.

Previously I was using child window and added to the application window, acts as the overlay to the whole page.

But my requirement is the exactly between the two rows in table.

Can any one help, how to do this in Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want edit the all selected records on table. For this you can use Property.ValueChangeListener. When event occurs you can get all selected records and put them to wherever you want. Of course you must create dynamic form elements for every selected record.